# Use a part from a different module in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

What I'm trying to do is create a site in Orchard that doesn't have a way for a user to register.  An administrator will create the users.

What I have is module that defines the parts, records, views, etc.  That is basically working.

Now what I'm trying to do is add a UserPart (from Orchard.Users) to one of the parts in my module.

I'm not sure how to do that.  I need the fields displayed for the UserPart with the fields for the parent part in the same view.  This also needs to be done in a way that when a save happens, all of the UserPart fields get sent to the Orchard.Users module.

Any suggestions, pointers or links on how to do that?

Thanks!

UPDATE...

The Activating Filter is an interesting idea.  I initially chose the migration route. For now, I'll try and get that method working.

For simplicity, let's say I have a "Company" type (there's more to the actual type) that has a "CompanyName" and a UserPart.

Here's what the different pieces look like...

Migrations.cs (simplified)

```
public int Create()
{
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("CompanyPartRecord", table =>  table.ContentPartRecord()
.Column("CompanyName", DbType.AnsiString, c => c.WithLength(50))
.Column("UserId", DbType.Int32));

SchemaBuilder.CreateForeignKey("FK_CompanyPartRecord_UserPartRecord", "CompanyPartRecord", new[] {"UserId" }, "Orchard.Users", "UserPartRecord", new[] { "Id" })

ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Company", type => type.WithPart("CommonPart").WithPart("UserPart"));
}
```

CompanyPartRecord

```
public class CompanyPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual int? UserId { get; set; }
}
```

CompanyPart

```
public class CompanyPart : ContentPart<CompanyPartRecord>
{
    internal LazyField<UserPart> UserPartField = new LazyField<UserPart>();

    public string CompanyName
    {
        get { return Record.CompanyName; }
        set { Record.CompanyName = value; }
    }

    public UserPart User
    {
        get { return UserPartField.Value;}
        set { UserPartField.Value = value; }
    }
}
```

Handler

```
public class CompanyPartHandler : ContentHandler
{
    private readonly IContentManager _manager;

    public CompanyPartHandler(IRepository<CompanyPartRecord> repository, IContentManager manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));            
        OnActivated<CompanyPart>(OnActivatedHandler);
    }

    private void OnActivatedHandler(ActivatedContentContext context, CompanyPart part)
    {
        if(part.User == null)
        {
            part.User = _manager.Create<UserPart>("User");
        }
        else
        {
            part.User = _manager.Get<UserPart>(part.User.Id);
        }
    }        
}
```

Driver

```
public class CompanyPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<CompanyPart>
{
    protected override DriverResult Editor(CompanyPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Company_Edit", () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: "Parts/Company", 
                                                                                    Model: part, Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(CompanyPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class AdminCompanyController : Controller, IUpdateModel
{
    private readonly IOrchardServices _services;
    private readonly INotifier _notifier;
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;
    private readonly ITransactionManager _transactionManager;
    private readonly Localizer T = NullLocalizer.Instance;

    public AdminCompanyController(IOrchardServices services)
    {
        _services = services;
        _notifier = services.Notifier;
        _contentManager = services.ContentManager;
        _transactionManager = services.TransactionManager;
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var company = _contentManager.New<CompanyPart>("Company");
        var model = _contentManager.BuildEditor(company);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult CreatePOST()
    {
        var contentItem = _contentManager.New<CompanyPart>("Company");
        var model = _contentManager.UpdateEditor(contentItem, this);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _transactionManager.Cancel();
            return View(model);
        }

        _contentManager.Create(contentItem.ContentItem);
        _notifier.Information(T("Company has been saved"));

        return RedirectToAction("Index");            
    }


    public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
    {
        var contentItem = _services.ContentManager.Get(Id);
        dynamic model = _services.ContentManager.BuildEditor(contentItem);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    public ActionResult EditPOST(int Id)
    {
        var contentItem = _contentManager.Get<CompanyPart>(Id);
        var model = _contentManager.UpdateEditor(contentItem, this);
        _notifier.Information(T("Company has been saved"));

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
    {
        var contentItem = _contentManager.Get<CompanyPart>(Id);
        _contentManager.Destroy(contentItem.ContentItem);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    bool IUpdateModel.TryUpdateModel<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties, string[] excludeProperties)
    {
        return TryUpdateModel(model, prefix, includeProperties, excludeProperties);
    }

    public void AddModelError(string key, LocalizedString errorMessage)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(key, errorMessage.ToString());
    }
}
```

View (create)

```
@{ Layout.Title = T("Add Company").ToString(); }

@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost()) 
{    
@Display(Model)
}
```

Editor Template

```
@model SDS.Models.CompanyPart

<fieldset>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName)
</fieldset>

@*

What goes here to display UserPart?

*@
```

So here's where I'm at.  I can see the ContentItem (CompanyType).  I can put in the name and save it.  The name is getting saved to the db.  Right now the UserPart is getting saved to the db, but all of the fields are blank.

The part I'm stuck on is what to put in the editor template to display the UserPart fields so that the values get to the UserPart driver and ultimately the db.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just attach the UserPart of Orchard.Users to your custom content type that is created in your module

Comment: OK, how is that done?

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense to me. It sounds like you want to extend the orchard user with your own data. Can you give a detailed specific example?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to create a "Company" type.  The Company type has 2 properties.  A "Name" property and a "User" property.  The Name property is just a string.  The User property is a UserPart.  The idea is that an Admin will create a Company (i.e. no user registration).  Once the Company is created, the user will get an email that will bring them back to the site.  At that point the user will set their password.  From that point on, the standard login mechanism will be used.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't attach parts to parts, you attach parts to content items, and you can do that in multiple ways.

You can do it through the admin screen, but that isn't a code driven solution and would have problems if you have multiple environments or need to redeploy a fresh version of code.

You can attach the part when you create a new content item in the migration. This might be a good solution, if you already ran your migration you could possibly do it with an update migration. This allows the part to be managed through the admin screen, but has downsides because it can be removed and if you have code that relies on the part then you will start having errors.

The last way and best way is to attach the part dynamically using an [Activating Filter.](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-content-handlers/#built-in-filter-types)

> ActivatingFilter class - Attaches a part to a content type from code. As opposed to attaching parts via migrations, parts attached using this filter will neither be displayed in the Dashboard, nor users will be able to remove them from types. It's a legitimate way of attaching parts that should always exist on a given content type.

So to do this:
1. Add a reference to Orchard.Users to your custom project.
2. Create a handler for you part. Such as MyPartHandler
3. Then add the activating handler like so

```
Filters.Add(ActivatingFilter.For<UserPart>("MyContentType"));
```

So now anywhere in your code you can access the UserPart if you already have your part, or the content item using

```
var userPart = myPart.As<UserPart>();
```

Comment: I'm giving this method a try.  I can see that the ContentItem has a UserPart.  However, the UserPart fields don't get displayed.  I tried a save just to see what happened.  What happened was a new record was inserted into the UserPartRecord table, but all the values are NULL.  How do I get the UserPart to show up on the UI?